# CoreData Concurrency - Model attribute passing between threads

Tags: objective-c, core-data, concurrency, thread-safety, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying make my existing Core Data app more UI responsive.
For this reason I want to move a part of my Core Data handling to the background.
I've created a 2nd managedContext with concurrency type "NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType".
I've read that I can't pass managedContexts and managedObjects between 2 threads.
I'm using NSStrings containing an UUID (from CoreBluetooth) to identify the stored objects.
I'm moving around those strings several times in my app.
I've noticed many times that my entire UI gets completely blocked (without big CPU usage/if the UI is blocked that the CPU usage drops to 0%). I think their's somewhere a deadlock with the CoreData stuff, because if I revert my code to not use the concurrency anymore everything works fine.

My question now is, if passing an attribute from my CoreData model from one thread to another is allowed or not. 
Do I have to pass the managedObjectID instead of my identification string?

Thank you very much for any help

Linard

Comment: As you've described it, it doesn't sound like a problem. If you post some code, it might be possible to better analyze the situation.

Comment: In the meantime I changed my code to use a second/private context on a per method basis instead of one private context for an entire class and I haven't had a deadlock or UI block yet. Maybe that was the mistake...

Comment: Just to be clear, you were using one context **per class**, not per thread or per queue?

Comment: Exactly one per class. To be sure that I call the context on the right thread I used performBlock: or performBlockAndWait: